# Why is my C# prime number calculator not working?

Tags: c#, console-application

It is my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsolePrimeNumberCalculator1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "ConsolePrimeNumberCalculator1";
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int a, b, c, d, e = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out a))
            {
                if (a > 1)
                {
                    for (b = 2; b <= a; b++)
                    {
                        d = 2;
                        c = 1;
                        while (d < b)
                        {
                            if (b % d == 0)
                            {
                                c = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                            d++;
                        }
                        if (c == 1)
                        {
                            e = 1 + e;
                        }
                        if (a > 50000)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Number is Big");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (a < 50001)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number is Small");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is not Integer");
            }
            if (a < 1)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(input, out a))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number is Small");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem:

I wrote 2.3. But my application wrote this:

"Number is not integer" and "Number is Small"

"Number is not integer" is a true sentence. But I think "Number is Small" is a false sentence. Because 2.3 is not smaller than 1. Why does my application wrote "Number is Small"? Is it C# bug?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second `if (a < 1)` after the else

Comment: "not integer and small numbers"

Comment: You check that above too

Comment: Just an advice, name your variables in such way that it is clear what they mean. That will improve the readability of your code.

Comment: I found my question answer. Answer: Because we are using int instead of double and program cannot detect int. Please delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your TryParse calls cannot parse it to an integer (this is why they are returning false).

This line:

```
int.TryParse(input, out a)
```

Will return false and a will be 0.

So when you hit your final if:

```
if (a < 1)
{
   if (!int.TryParse(input, out a))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Number is Small");
   }
}
```

a is zero to start, it still can't parse it, so a remains zero and you hit this write.

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse("2.3", out a);` will try to parse `"2.3"` as an integer, and if it succeeds, it will assign it's value to `a` (currently `0`).

As `TryParse` fails (cannot convert `"2.3"` to `int`), it never assigns the value to `a`, which remains `0`, hence the code falls in the else block.

Answer (score 1):

`int a = 0` stills `0` after parsing because the parse function fails... Try to debug and see it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have `int a = 0` than
`(!int.TryParse(input, out a))` fails and
`a` is less than 1 that's why it is printing "Number is Small"